# Как вытащить часть строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка:

> uid=new_tracks_player84&comment=file-name&st=/design/images/audio30-856.txt&file=/vardata/modules/musicdb/samples/201209/d52d5cdf039d23b25f8af73e0b7b5504.mp3&auto=play

Как в Java c помощью регулярного выражения вытащить:

```
/vardata/modules/musicdb/samples/201209/d52d5cdf039d23b25f8af73e0b7b5504.mp3
```

т.е. значение между file= и &

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592324/6275986

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если не парсить URL, а через regexp, то можно например так:
`Pattern.compile("file=(.*\\.mp3)&");`
и вытащив 1 capturing group: `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! :)